# the order in which result of a set is printed in Python

Tags: python

I do the following in the command prompt:

```
>>> a=set()
>>> for i in range(0,8):
...     a.add((i,j))
...
```

the answer that I get when I print it is like this:

```
>>> a
set([(2, 7), (4, 7), (6, 7), (5, 7), (7, 7), (0, 7), (1, 7), (3, 7)])
```

I understand that its printing out the results in the way its stored. But is there a way I can get it ordered? Say for example in this way:

```
(0,7), (1,7), (2,7), (3,7), ...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right that a set doesn't store its elements in sorted order. If you want to get a list of the elements in the set in sorted order you can use the built-in function [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
>>> a
set([(2, 7), (4, 7), (6, 7), (5, 7), (7, 7), (0, 7), (1, 7), (3, 7)])
>>> sorted(a)
[(0, 7), (1, 7), (2, 7), (3, 7), (4, 7), (5, 7), (6, 7), (7, 7)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list instead of a set if you don't need the set features.

If you really want an ordered set, on Python 2.7 you can use `collections.OrderedDict`, the `.viewkeys()` method can be used to get a set-like proxy, while looping over the dictionary will get you the keys in order.

Or you can implement your own `OrderedSet` using `collections.MutableSet` and `collections.OrderedDict` (or another implementation of OrderedDict if you have Python 2.6).

```
class OrderedSet(collections.MutableSet):
    def __init__(self, iterable=[]):
        self._data = collections.OrderedDict((x, None) for x in iterable)

    def __contains__(self, x):
        return x in self._data

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._data)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)

    def __le__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, OrderedSet) and hasattr(self._data, 'viewkeys'):
            return self._data.viewkeys() <= other._data.viewkeys()
        return super(OrderedSet, self).__le__(other)

    def add(self, value):
        self._data[value] = None

    def discard(self, value):
        self._data.pop(value, None)

    def remove(self, value):
        self._data.pop(value)

    def pop(self):
        return self._data.popitem()[0]

    def clear(self):
        self._data.clear()

    def __ior__(self, other):
        self._data.update((x, None) for x in other)
        return self

    def __iand__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, collections.Set):
            other = self._from_iterable(other)
        for value in list(self._data):
            if value not in other:
                self.remove(value)
        return self

    def __and__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, collections.Iterable):
            return NotImplemented
        if not isinstance(other, collections.Set):
            other = self._from_iterable(other)
        return self._from_iterable(value for value in self if value in other)
```